# How do I implement stack in PL/SQL?

Tags: plsql, oracle11g

In Python it would look something like this:

```
class Stack:
     def __init__(self):
         self.items = []

     def isEmpty(self):
         return self.items == []

     def push(self, item):
         self.items.append(item)

     def pop(self):
         return self.items.pop()

     def peek(self):
         return self.items[len(self.items)-1]

     def size(self):
         return len(self.items)
```

Which data structure do I use and how do I implement stack in Oracle PL/SQL?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve the object oriented kind of things by using `OBJECT` types.

Like a `class` in other programming languages, you can use `OBJECT` in PL/SQL for encapsulating data.

For example the stack definition: (lifted from ORACLE documentation link.... posted down below. You can find definition of below declaration in that link).

```
CREATE TYPE Stack AS OBJECT ( 
   max_size INTEGER, 
   top      INTEGER,
   position IntArray,
   MEMBER PROCEDURE initialize,
   MEMBER FUNCTION full RETURN BOOLEAN,
   MEMBER FUNCTION empty RETURN BOOLEAN,
   MEMBER PROCEDURE push (n IN INTEGER),
   MEMBER PROCEDURE pop (n OUT INTEGER)
);
```

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A97630_01/appdev.920/a96624/13_elems32.htm

Answer (score 0):

You can implement stacks in pl/sql using Associative array tables.
Consider the following example.
You can read more at the following locations:

[Oracle Collections Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/plsql-collections-and-records.html)

[Collections Tutorial](https://www.oracletutorial.com/?s=collections)

```
declare
  type stack_type is table of binary_integer index by binary_integer;
                           ---^ Use your data type here    
  stack stack_type;

  procedure push( p_element in binary_integer ) as
                          -----^ Use your data type here
  begin
    stack( stack.count + 1 ) := p_element;
  end push;

  procedure pop as
  begin
    stack.delete( stack.count ) ;
  end;
 
  function find ( p_element in binary_integer )
                          -----^ Use your data type here
           return boolean as
  begin
    for element in 1 .. stack.count loop
      if stack( element ) = p_element then
        return true;
      end if;
    end loop;
    return false;
  end;
 
  function top
           return binary_integer as
           -------^ Use your data type here    
  begin
    return stack( stack.count );
  end;
 
 begin
    push( 123 );
    push( 456 );
    push( 678 );
    push( 929 );
    push( 104 );
 
    for element in 1 .. stack.count loop
      dbms_output.put_line( 'Element:' || element || ' Value: ' || stack( element ) );
    end loop;

    dbms_output.put_line( 'Find|Top:' || top() );
   
    if find( 929 ) then
      dbms_output.put_line( '929 Found' );
    else
      dbms_output.put_line( '929 Not found');
    end if;
   
    if find(321) then
       dbms_output.put_line( '321 Found' );
    else
      dbms_output.put_line( '321 Not found');
    end if;  
   
    while stack.count > 0 loop
      dbms_output.put_line( 'Pop|Top:' || top() );
      pop();
    end loop;
   
 end;
```